# Many templates or one in django project?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

There is a django project that perform a **user.is_authenticated** check, and **account type** (3 types) check. It should behave different ways for different account types and for guest account.

**Question:** What is the most efficient way of managing templates for different account types?

1. All checks in one template.
2. More checks in views. Different templates for different account types.

I think the first way to work faster than the second. If I'm wrong I'd prefer to do that the second way because it's easier for me to manage and develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on use case details. If you're changing lot of templates it would be better to change some extend or include tag path in templates globally (for example using context_processor and getting this template path from variable).

Also you should be avoiding any logic in your templates, because that is not what they are for. Other solutions are custom template tags, mixins for your views etc. Consider what's most dry solution for your use case and do that solution instead of considering what works faster.